# iOS6 bug in UITapGestureRecognizer gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:?

Tags: ios, ios6, exc-bad-access, uitapgesturerecognizer

The following code in my view controller results in an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` at the `touch.view` call:

```
- (BOOL)handleSingleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]]) {   // <<<< EXC_BAD_ACCESS HERE
        // we touched a button, slider, or other UIControl
        return NO; // ignore the touch
    }
    [self.view endEditing:YES];  // dismiss the keyboard
    return YES; // handle the touch    
}
```

`touch` appears to be a zombie.  Specifically, `touch` is set to an address, and the debugger thinks that's a `UITouch` pointer, but it doesn't have any properties:

[image: as can be seen in the debugger]

This did not happen in iOS 4.x.  So iOS 6 bug or my fault?

The gesture recognizer is set up as follows (in the ViewController):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:shouldReceiveTouch:)];
[tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
tapRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
[tapRecognizer release];
```

**UPDATE/SOLUTION:**

Thanks to Rob for pointing out the user error on my part.  Not only that, but I don't actually need the TapRecognizer since I just want to know a touch happened.

Here's the correct code to dismiss the on-screen keyboard with a touch anywhere but in a UIControl:

In the ViewController's `viewDidLoad`:

```
UIGestureRecognizer *myRecognizer = [[UIGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
[myRecognizer setDelegate:self];
myRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:myRecognizer];
[myRecognizer release];
```

And:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch  {

if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]]) {
    // we touched a button, slider, or other UIControl
    return NO; // ignore the touch
}

[self.view endEditing:YES];  // dismiss the keyboard
return YES; // handle the touch
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a method, `handleSingleTap:shouldReceiveTouch:`, whose signature does not conform to the permissible signatures. See the [Overview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009279-CH1-DontLinkElementID_1) section of *UIGestureRecognizer Class Reference.* It should only have the one parameter, the gesture recognizer.

I think you may be confusing the handler with the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol method [`gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009280-CH1-SW1).

Comment: Wow, you're absolutely right.  Thanks so much.  I've edited my question above to include the correct code.  The only question remains is why this didn't show up in iOS 4.x (same code).